# How to transfer text message backup file to my Samsung Galaxy S III?

Tags: sms, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I used "SMS Backup & Restore" to create an sms.xml file with all my text messages from my old phone. My new phone, Samsung Galaxy S III, can't mount as USB mass storage, so I can't figure out how to transfer the file. I've used gmtp to transfer media files to the phone before.

What's the best solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it out, but try the WiFi File Explorer by Dooblou.

Here's the link:  http://www.pcworld.com/appguide/app.html?id=648691&expand=false

Sounds like it should do the job you're looking for.

Comment: Seems like the free version is only for phone->computer transfer. But it's a good idea: I'll look for FTP server apps.

Comment: Yeah anything wireless should work as long as the computer is able to see the phone.

Comment: I did it with [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en), and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Perfect,glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can try move the file from card reader, bluetooth, or download from email. I use AST android sms transfer,   this software have the same functions, and I feel it's easy to use. AST android sms transfer website :   http://www.android-sms-transfer.com